# SNS Webhook continues to receive the same request over and over

Tags: amazon-sns

I've set up a SNS webhook -- an endpoint that subscribes to a topic. Whenever my app publishes to the topic (users), the topic successfully forwards the data as a POST request to my webhook endpoint (/users). 
However, after sending the request, my endpoint continues to receive the same request over and over again. Does anyone know why SNS after successfully making a request to my endpoint continues to send the same request? Upon receiving the request, does my endpoint need to tell my topic that the data has been received? Would I do this with the SNS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was my mistake. I was using express (node) and in the endpoint that was the SNS webhook, I did not return with a response. Adding this line of code as the final line in the endpoint fixed my issue:

```
return res.status(200).json({success: true});
```